# formfield_for_foreignkey and Inline Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I only want to show the players related to team in a particular fixture. Normally when I do it, it shows me all my players from the database. Here is my models.py

```
class InningsCard(models.Model):
    fixture = models.ForeignKey(Fixture)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    runs = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)
    wickets = models.IntegerField(max_length=6, default=0)
    overs = models.FloatField(max_length=6, default=0.0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.team)

class BattingDetail(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('no', 'not out'),
        ('bowled', 'bowled'),
        ('caught', 'caught'),
        ('lbw', 'lbw'),
    )
    innings = models.ForeignKey(InningsCard)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    runs = models.IntegerField(max_length=5, default=0)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='no')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.player)
```

Now and here is my admin.py to include formfield_for_foreignkey, but it doesn't work.

```
class BattingInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BattingDetail
    extra = 0

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):

        if db_field.name == 'player':
            kwargs = Player.objects.filter(team = request.team)
        else:
            pass

        return super(BattingInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)


class InningCardAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [BattingInline]
```

where could i be going wrong?

//mouse

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You're replacing the entire `kwargs` with the queryset. `kwargs` must be a dictionary, and the particular key you're looking for is 'queryset':

   ```
   kwargs['queryset'] = Player.objects.filter(team=request.team)
   ```
2. I'm almost positive request isn't going to actually have an attribute `team`. Unless you've added it yourself in some code not displayed here, you need to find another way to get at the current "team". You can parse out the team id from `request.path` and use that for the lookup, for example.

As a side note, the `else` clause is unnecessary if you're just going to `pass` there.