# Adding to List Style Entries in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I would like to create a model where the user can add objects of a model to a list in Django.

For example:

```
class Receipt(models.Model):
    items = #many to many maybe? but their is only one receipt for each item object
    #other fields

class Item(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField()
    #otherfields

Class ItemPurchase(models.Model):
    receipt = model.ForeignKey(Receipt)
    item = model.ForeignKey(Item)
    quantity = model.IntegerField()
    #other fields specific to this Receipt
```

Then in the admin, I want to allow the user to add Item objects to their current Receipt objects in the admin panel, and create an ItemPurchase record, but how would I best do this? The Receipt cannot be associated until the Receipt is made...

Comment: Read the documentation section about [inline objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlines)

Comment: Thank you so much @Hedde I have NO idea how I missed such a cool aspect of Django. I'm still pretty new to it and it seems to have tons of built-in goodies to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Django's inline feature combined with custom queryset returns is exactly what I needed to do everything I wanted, thanks @Hedde for the tip!

Read about inlines:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

This helped in multiple ways, I just needed a push in the right direction:
[formfield_for_foreignkey and Inline Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9640103/formfield-for-foreignkey-and-inline-admin)